# How to find a common element in two ordered linked lists in linear time?

Tags: performance, linked-list

Let A and B be two ordered linked lists. Write a method finding a common element of A and B, if it exists. The running time should be linear

My solution:

`public void search(SLLNode A, SLLNodeB){
          for(int i=0;i<A.size();i++){
             for(int j=0;j<B.size();j++){
                 if(a.head==b.head){
                    return a.head;
                  }
                 else{
                   a.head=a.next;
                   b.head=b.next;
                  }
              }
            }
           }`

The problem is I am not sure if this solution even works. I also don't think that this is linear time because of the nested loops.

Is there a faster way to write this? Thanks in advance. I haven't written code in over a year so I am a bit lost on the syntax.

Comment: Think of the way mergesort uses two sorted lists to get one sorted output. You could apply the same method and look for two identical elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible linear solution to the problem.

```
public static Integer common(List<Integer> l1, List<Integer> l2) {
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    while ( j < l1.size() && k < l2.size() ) {
        if (l1.get(j).intValue() == l2.get(k).intValue()) return l1.get(j);
        else if (l1.get(j).intValue() > l2.get(k).intValue()) k++;
        else j++;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Test scenario:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> l1 = new LinkedList();
    List<Integer> l2 = new LinkedList();
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) l1.add(i);
    for (int i=10; i<20; i++) l2.add(i);
    l1.add(15);
    System.out.println(common(l1,l2));
}
```

**Approach:** 
Lets say the lists are l1 and l2. Elements are denoted as e1, e2 ... etc

You go through each element of the lists one by one and check:

- If e1 in l1 == e1 in l2 then return e1
- If e1 in l1 > e1 in l2 then move one element forward in l2
- If e1 in l1 < e1 in l2 then move one element forward in l1

Keep repeating the above steps until either one of the list reaches the end or one of the element is equal.